# Generating models/poco classes to be used by entity framework from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t4

I can generate poco classes using [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/) which works perfectly fine, but now I have bit different requirements.

I want to generate two types of model projects from database.

- Internal model
- External model

Internal model will most likely carbon copy of sql with slight modifications so this isn't a problem, we can keep try using EF tools for that.

BUT for external model we need to exclude some tables and columns to be part of model.

***To not make things too complicated and duplicate my plan is to somehow automate this process.***

How automation would work ?

Maybe I will have two config files in json or xml or whatever, one for internal and another for external which will have list of tables & columns to exclude or re map when creating classes etc..

Is this something possible ? I know very little about T4 templates but maybe they can be used but I am not 100% sure, any guide or experience would be very appreciated.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not an EF guy. However, I have used Razor templates to generate POCO classes before and it works extremely well. I used Razor because I can host it outside of visual studio (i.e. in my own app). You could use reflection and attributes on your data model to control how to generate the external model.

Comment: Just use the EF Reverse POCO template to generate the two models

Comment: @ErikEJ then we will have to manually update models with every database change, as we are following database first at the moment, also we don't know how to sync both projects - maybe I didn't understood you right

Comment: You can invoke tt templates from the command line, and the generated code can be customized to your hearts desire, and the generated classes can be partial - suggest you watch the Pluralsight course

Comment: @ErikEJ I did watched this one - https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/t4-templates/table-of-contents , but it's not in as depth as I would require to fix the case scenario I described above

Comment: I meant this one: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/code-first-entity-framework-legacy-databases